# Convert date from one timezone to local timezone

Tags: java, jodatime

I am using Java 8 and attempting to convert a timestamp from one time zone to another. The time stamp will be in the user's time zone e.g.

```
//  2016-04-11T12:00:00Z
long sourceTime = 1460372400000L;
timezoneConverter(sourceTime, "America/New_York");
```

However, when using Joda time, or Java 8 LocalDateTime/Instant, when I pass the timestamp it is adjusted to the user's time zone - I don't need this to happen, as it is already in the user's timezone (all timestamps will be sent in the user's local time).

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = 
    ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(1460372400000L),
                            ZoneId.of("America/New_York"))
```

results in

```
2016-04-11T07:00-04:00[America/New_York]
```

instead of

```
2016-04-11T12:00-04:00[America/New_York]
```

Is there any way around this?

Thanks!

Comment: I fear your statement "it is a time stamp from the user's time zone." indicates a misunderstanding of the meaning of timestamps such as `1460372400000L`. This sort of global timestamps is not related to any timezones but just fixed to UTC+00:00.

Answer (score 1):

`1460372400000L` is `Mon, 11 Apr 2016 11:00:00 GMT` or `Mon, 11 Apr 2016 12:00:00 BST`

`2016-04-11T11:00:00Z` is `2016-04-11T07:00-04:00[America/New_York]` so you are converting from one time zone to another.

If you just want the local time zone, I suggest you use `LocalDateTime`

```
LocalDateTime dt = LocalDateTime.ofEpochSecond(1460376000L, 0 ,  ZoneOffset.ofHours(0));
System.out.println(dt);
```

prints

```
2016-04-11T12:00
```

Comment: The timestamp shouldn't be adjusted in my case - it is a time stamp from the user's time zone.

Comment: @StephenWithAPh1986 this is what `LocalDateTime` is for. A DateTime without a timezone.

Answer (score 0):

```
long sourceTime = 1460372400000L;
//Select your timezone
TimeZone utcTimeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(utcTimeZone);
calendar.setTimeInMillis(sourceTime);
```

//Get Current Time Zone

```
LocalTime time = LocalTime.now();
System.out.println("Local Time Zone: "+ZoneId.systemDefault().toString());
System.out.println("Current local time : " + time);
```